# 'realm/util/features.h' file not found Sporadically Occurs when Re-Installing Pods. Realm-JS

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

Very occasionally the Realm pod (Realm-JS) will actually build and run correctly. The majority of the time in order for it to build without the "file not found" error I have to:

- Delete derived data and project build folder
- Clean pod cache $pod cache clean --all
- Delete and reinstall yarn
- Delete and reinstall pods
- Quitting the sim (?)

Sometimes I'm going through those steps 5 times before it works. Every time I have to reinstall pods it's hours of pain trying to get Realm to build again.

- Pods version 1.10.0
- Realm version 10.2.0
- Xcode 12.3
- React Native 0.63.1

(Have tried suggestions mentioned on other SO posts and Git.)

Comment: Are you sure your Realm version is 10.2.0? The current version is 10.7.2. Also, your cocoapods need a minor update.

Comment: Thx, I think 10.2.0 is the latest of Realm JS flava.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current workaround - seems to consistently work.  It can burn 20-30 minutes.

Steps to escape the Realm of Hell:

- Delete yarn modules
- Delete pods
- Delete derived data
- $yarn cache clean
- $pod cache clean --all
- Erase all contents and settings from the simulator
- Close the simulator
- Clean Xcode build folder
- Close Xcode
- Restart computer
- Flush every toilet in the house
- Install yarn modules and pods
- Wait 4 minutes for Xcode to build+run to the potential Realm failure point